# How to get more details from result regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

Here I have a test string :

```
apple 01x100 02x200 03x150
banana 01x50 02 03x10
```

What I want as result :

```
{ "apple" : { "100":["01"], "200":["02"], "150":["03"] }, 
  "banana" : {"50":["01"], "10":["02","03"]}
```

I'm trying to use regex in javascript to parse string. The regex string

```
/(apple|banana)((?:\s)*(?:(?:[0-9]+)(?:\s)*)*x(?:[0-9])+)+/gi
```

Result:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-26    `apple 01x100 02x200 03x150`
Group 1.    0-5 `apple`
Group 2.    19-26   ` 03x150`

Match 2
Full match  27-48   `banana 01x50 02 03x10`
Group 1.    27-33   `banana`
Group 2.    39-48   ` 02 03x10`
```

As you see, in Match 1 - Group 2, only 03x150 show, 01x100 and 02x200 doesn't. In Full match it show all. Any idea to fix this and get the result I want ? Thanks

Comment: What is the rule by which `02` gets associated with key `10` in the final output?

Comment: 01 means type of quality, 100 means quantity. Also, 02 means quality, 10 means quantity. In this case, banana type 02 and 03 get the same quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```js
const input = `
apple 01x100 02x200 03x150
banana 01x50 02 03x10
lemon 02x12 15 16 17x21
`

const parse = data => {
    const obj = {}
    const findFruits = /(\w+)\s+(.*)/g
    const findMore = /\s*([\d\s]+)x(\d+)/g
    let temp
    while (temp = findFruits.exec(data)) {
        const tempObj = obj[temp[1]] = {}
        const temp2 = temp[2]
        while (temp = findMore.exec(temp2)) {
            tempObj[temp[2]] = temp[1].split(' ')
        }
    }
    return obj
}

const out = parse(input)
console.log(out)
```